# Selenium Python - get elements and click on each

Tags: python, selenium

i want to store elements in a list and click on each of them one by one. But I have to reach the < u > - Element, because .click() only works, when I click on that < u > - xpath and not on the class-Element.

```
<a href="javascript:doQuery(...);" class="report">
    <u>Test1</u>

<a href="javascript:doQuery(...);" class="report">
    <u>Test2</u>

<a href="javascript:doQuery(...);" class="report">
    <u>Test3</u>
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Your code trials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector for this.

```py
selector = '.report > u'

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)

for elem in elements:
    elem.click()
```

This selector `.report > u` will select all `<u>` elements whose parent is an element with the `report` class.

[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)